# pandoc - disable capitalization of emphasis markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

For my program, I have a markdown document that I use to produce both a Unix man page as well as a plain text document.

```
pandoc -s -w plain -o program.txt program.md
pandoc --no-wrap -s -w man -o program.1 program.md
```

The content in the markdown with double asterisks (e.g. `**foobar**`) is used to express emphasis results in **bold** text in the man page. But in the text output, it results in UPPER CASE.

For example:

`echo '**foobar**' | pandoc -w plain`

results in:

`FOOBAR`

But I'd rather it ignore the emphasis tagging and just output `foobar` in the plain text output.

The best I've been able to come up with is to use a `sed` expression to strip out all the emphasis tags:

```
cat program.md | sed s/\*\*//g | pandoc --no-wrap -s -w plain -o program.txt
```

Is there a more formal way to do this?

Comment: You can always produce the text document _from the manpage_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a Pandoc filter that converts strong text to normal text when outputting to pain text.

There is a filter that does just this: https://github.com/sergiocorreia/panflute-filters/blob/master/filters/remove-strong.py

(It uses Panflute so you need to `pip install panflute`, and have python 2.7+ installed)

---

You also may to replace this line:

`if isinstance(elem, pf.Strong)`

With this  one:

`if isinstance(elem, pf.Strong) and doc.format=='plain'`

(Or just run the filter only for text output!)